# Подскажите директивы компилятора gcc

Tags: linux, компиляция, gcc, makefile, arm

я компилю hostapd под arm командой: `make CC=/root/arm-linux-musleabi-native/bin/arm-linux-musleabi-gcc`ранее сыпали ошибки на отсутствия библиотек, исправил это линками на нужные библиотеки, теперь все компилится, но при запуске hostapd теперь выдает такую ошибку:

```
Error loading shared library libnl-3.so.200: No such file or directory (needed by hostapd)
Error loading shared library libnl-genl-3.so.200: No such file or directory (needed by hostapd)
Error loading shared library libcrypto.so.3: No such file or directory (needed by hostapd)
Error relocating hostapd: nla_nest_start: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_sub: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_EncryptUpdate: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_CipherUpdate: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_DecryptInit_ex: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_put_u32: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: HMAC_Final: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nl_recvmsgs: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_bin2bn: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_get_u16: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: DH_generate_key: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_is_one: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_DecryptFinal_ex: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nl_send_auto_complete: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: AES_set_encrypt_key: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_des_cbc: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: DES_ecb_encrypt: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: HMAC_Init_ex: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nl_socket_get_fd: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_aes_128_cbc: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nl_cb_clone: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_put: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_EncryptInit_ex: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: OPENSSL_cleanse: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_next: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: AES_wrap_key: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_DecryptUpdate: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_aes_256_cbc: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_CTX_new: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nlmsg_data: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: DH_get0_key: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_rshift1: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nlmsg_free: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: DH_new: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_aes_256_ecb: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_nest_end: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: DH_size: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: genlmsg_put: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nlmsg_alloc: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_DigestInit_ex: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: __mktime64: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_cmp: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_get_string: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nl_cb_alloc: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: AES_unwrap_key: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_put_flag: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: DH_set0_pqg: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_value_one: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_parse: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: __gmtime64: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_get_rfc3526_prime_1536: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_CipherInit_ex: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_put_string: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nl_socket_alloc_cb: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: __select_time64: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_sha1: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: HMAC_Update: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_get_u8: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_rc4: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_put_nested: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: DES_set_key: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nl_cb_err: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: DH_compute_key: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_MD_CTX_new: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_num_bits: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_len: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nl_cb_set: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: AES_set_decrypt_key: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_is_word: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: HMAC_CTX_new: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: __gettimeofday_time64: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_bn2bin: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_set_word: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_new: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: genl_ctrl_resolve: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_put_u8: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_mod_inverse: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_md5: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_div: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nl_socket_set_buffer_size: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_free: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: genlmsg_attrlen: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_data: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_put_u64: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_DigestFinal: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_CTX_free: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: RAND_bytes: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nl_socket_add_membership: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_aes_128_ecb: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: genl_connect: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_get_u64: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_mod_exp: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_clear_free: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_parse_nested: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_type: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_rc2_ecb: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_EncryptFinal_ex: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nl_socket_free: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_get_u32: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_aes_192_ecb: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_add: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_des_ede3_cbc: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: HMAC_CTX_free: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_sha256: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nlmsg_hdr: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_MD_CTX_free: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_is_zero: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_put_u16: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_aes_192_cbc: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nl_cb_put: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: BN_mod_mul: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nla_ok: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: DH_free: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: nl_socket_set_nonblocking: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: __clock_gettime64: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: genlmsg_attrdata: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_DigestUpdate: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: __localtime64: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: DH_set0_key: symbol not found
Error relocating hostapd: EVP_md4: symbol not found
```

как понимаю нужно сделать библиотеки статическими, но ничего не получается, подскажите как правильно это сделать через make ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Установите на целевое устройство нужные библиотеки - `libnl-3.so.200`, `libnl-genl-3.so.200`, `libcrypto.so.3`

Comment: но на этом устройстве уже стоит и работает hostapd, значит можно компилировать без требования этих библиотек, просто я пробовал добавлять их имена как аргументы и использовать LDFLAGS, но не выходит

Comment: линками на нужные библиотеки - как именно это ?

Comment: @Andynvkz на целевой скорее всего стоит libcrypto.so.1